# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln (\ln n)}{\ln n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I test the following series for convergence?

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln (\ln n)}{\ln n}$$

I tried to use the integral test, but I don't think this has an elementary antiderivative. What else could I do to solve this question?

Comment: Compare to $\sum\frac{1}{\ln n}$ which diverges

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the integral test, $\frac{\ln (\ln n)}{\ln n}$ may not have an elementary antiderivative but

$$ \frac{\ln (\ln n)}{\ln n} > \frac{\ln (\ln n)}{n(\ln n)}$$

does have an antiderivative.

For a comparison test, notice that

$$ \ln (\ln n) > \frac{\ln n}{n}$$

for $n \geq 5$. Then divide and say that the series you have is bigger than $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: You have an ln too much in the numerator after the first >

Comment: @Milten could you explain? I don't see what you are referring to.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't you want to use $\ln(\ln n)>\frac{\ln n}{n}$, giving $\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}>\frac{\ln n}{n\ln n} = \frac 1n$? Maybe I misunderstood...

Comment: @Milten Ah no, right now I have exactly what I want because $\int \frac{\ln(\ln x)}{x\ln x}dx = \frac{1}{2}(\ln(\ln x))^2$. I have edited the post to make it clear that I am talking about two different approaches.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise you were integrating! Sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

By comparison test, show that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln(\ln(e^e))}{\ln(n)}\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln(\ln(n))}{\ln(n)}$$
for every $n\ge 16$.

Comment: Very nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

By [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we have

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^na_{2^n}= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n\ln (\ln (2^n)}{\ln (2^n)}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n\ln (n\ln 2)}{n\ln 2}$$

As an alternative by [limit comparison test](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html) with $\sum \frac 1n$

$$\frac{\frac{\ln (\ln (n)}{\ln (n)}}{\frac1n}=\frac{n\ln (\ln (n)}{\ln (n)}\to \infty$$

Comment: Should it say $2^na_{2^n}$ in the first sum?

Comment: @Milten Yes of course! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** For $n\geq  9$ we have 
$$\frac{\ln( \ln(n))}{\ln(n)} \geq \frac{\ln(\ln(e^2))}{\ln(n)} \geq \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(n)} \geq \frac{\ln(2)}{n}$$

Comment: If I use the integral test on ln(2)/n, should I integrate from 9 to infinity?

Comment: @AakashJajoo Yes... Anyhow, you probably already know that the harmonic series diverges....